# Why Android Studio 3.6 does not show the correct location of the error, when I use databinding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Android Studio 3.6

In my xml I use databinding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="testVariable"
            type="java.lang.String" />

        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="com.myproject.TestActivityJava" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/addTraderMainContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

but activity `TestActivityJava` not exist in my project. So as result when I try to run (in Android Studio 3.6) app I get error:

```
cannot find symbol
  protected TestActivityJava mHandler;
            ^
  symbol:   class TestActivityJava
  location: class TestActivityJavaBinding



e: myproject\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\myproject\databinding\TestActivityJavaBinding.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
  protected TestActivityJava mHandler;
            ^
  symbol:   class TestActivityJava
  location: class TestActivityJavaBinding


error: cannot generate view binders android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: failure, see logs for details.
  Cannot resolve type 'handler'
    at android.databinding.tool.util.L.printMessage(L.java:134)
    at android.databinding.tool.util.L.e(L.java:107)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.getResolvedType(Expr.java:370)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.ExprModel.lambda$resolveTypes$1(ExprModel.java:618)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
```

I go to `TestActivityJavaBinding.java:27` and find this:

```
public abstract class TestActivityJavaBinding extends ViewDataBinding {
  @NonNull
  public final ConstraintLayout addTraderMainContainer;

  @Bindable
  protected String mTestVariable;

  @Bindable
protected TestActivityJava mHandler;
```

This information not help in any way!!!
As you can see the Android Studio not help me to find a problem. 
**Why Android Studio does not indicate that the problem is in the xml file?**

P.S. After I delete my xml the problem is gone. And I success run my app.